# Rspec: How to stub private method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

Here is the error:

```
private method `desc' called for #<Array:0x0000010532e280>
```

the spec:

```
describe SubjectsController do  
  before(:each) do
    @subject = mock_model(Subject)
  end

    describe "#0002 - GET #index" do
    before(:each) do        
      subjects = [@subject, mock_model(Subject), mock_model(Subject)]
      Subject.stub!(:all).and_return(subjects)
      Subject.all.stub!(:desc).and_return(subjects)
      get :index
    end

    it { response.should be_success }
    it { response.should render_template("index") }
  end
end
```

and the controller:

```
def index
  @subjects = Subject.all(conditions: {company_id: current_user.company.id}).desc(:created_at)
end
```

I don't know how to solve this issue, can some one give me a hand ?
Could you also give me advise on how you would test this method ?
Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little more mocking & chaining than I prefer but, you can do this:

```
subjects = [...]
desc_mock = double("desc order mock")
desc_mock.should_receive(:desc).with(:created_at).and_return(subjects)

conditions = {...}
Subject.should_receive(:all).with(conditions).and_return(desc_mock)
```

You could also simplify this a lot by moving your query into a named scope that takes some parameters. Then your test could verify that Subject received your scope with the correct parameters like:

```
Subject.should_receive(:user_company).with(current_user.id).and_return(subjects)
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it is very confusing to test controllers and i can't find anything on google for complexe controller testing, not just resfull actions... If you have any suggestions, or links, or anything that could help me, please do !! ^^ Thx again

Comment: If the fact that you have to fake records makes it difficult, then stop using mocks and stubs for these methods. Try out factory girl, and create some real database content. The tests may be slower, but they're less brittle.

Answer (score 2):

[stub_chain](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-0/dir/stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods) should work here:

```
  Subject.stub_chain(:all,:desc) { [mock_model(Subject)]*2 }
```